# Generalization of Möbius inversion formula

Tags: mobius-function, mobius-inversion

A generalization of Möbius inversion formula guarantees that if we have $G(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} F\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$, then $F(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \mu(k) G\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$.

If we have $\sqrt{n}<x<n$, could it be correct if we state that if we have $G(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{x} F\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$, then $F(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{x} \mu(k) G\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$?

In case the above statement is generally incorrect, could it be correct depending on $F(n)$ and $G(n)$?

Comment: Have you tried any examples? Counterexamples shouldn't be hard to find. (Also the original statment is only true with some assumptions on $F$ and/or $G$.)